# What's the most efficient way to sort this alphabetically?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class structure:

```
List<myObject> myList = new List<myObject>();

myObject
{
    List<myOtherObject> myOtherList = new List<myOtherObject>();
}

myOtherObject
{
    string name;
}
```

What would be the best way to print all the `names` in `myList` alphabetically?

I could do this, but I suspect there is a more efficient way to achieve the same:

```
foreach(myObject a in myList)
{
    foreach(myOtherObject b in a.myOtherList)
    {
         newList.Add(b.name);
    }
}

//print newList alphabetically
```

EDIT:

I was able to change the structure so that now I only need to sort `myOtherList` now on the basis of its `name` property.

I tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to sort:

```
myOtherList.OrderBy(obj=>obj.name);
```

Does it sort it in place, or do I need to assign it to another list?

Comment: You need to use the result of the `OrderBy()` call in order to see your items sorted.

Comment: I need to store the ordered list back into a list of type `myOtherObject`. How could I do that?

Comment: I updated my answer to suggest a solution for always storing the list sorted.

Comment: To answer your last question: no, linq OrderBy does not sort in-place.  It returns an enumerator which will return the items in sorted order. You can call ToList() on that result to produce a new copy of the list in sorted order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using linq (method notation):

```
foreach (var result in myList
    .SelectMany(l => l.myOtherList)
    .OrderBy(obj => obj.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.name);
}
```

This flattens out the `myList` of `myOtherList`'s into a flat list of `myOtherObject`'s.

Comment: Could you have a look at my edit and tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: xbonez: how are you using this? The `.OrderBy()` will return a new `IOrderedEnumerable`, which, if iterated over (`foreach()`), will return in order.

Comment: I need to sort myOtherList and store it back into a list of the same type. I've never used LINQ before so excuse the noobishness

Comment: Alright, nevermind. I managed without assigning it to a list.

Comment: LINQ works on deferred execution (ie, the queries won't be run (like ordering or selecting) until you iterate across them. There are a number of methods (`.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, etc.) which return the iterated queries.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with LINQ pretty easily:

```
var sortedResults = from other in myList
                    from item in other.myOtherList
                    orderby item.name
                    select item;

foreach (var result in sortedResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.name);
}
```

If you need your data always sorted, then you may want to change `List<myOtherObject>` to [`SortedList<string, myOtherObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx), but I'm assuming `myOtherObject` is immutable, so the automatic sorting doesn't get corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @svick - I was worried about that, so I put it in the compiler, and found the issue - but you were faster to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to print all the names in the list alphabetically is to start off with an alphabetically sorted list.  Then you just print them in order.

Although such an answer might seem like an avoidance of the solution, if you are going to be doing a lot more printing in order than adding items, a List implementation that sorts upon insert might just be the correct answer.

Any other solution is going to require sorting the list first, or generating a sorted version of the list, unless you want to do some pretty horrible performance scans of the entire list to determine the "next lowest" item to print.

Comment: I don't think sorting in advance would work in this case, since it's actually a list of lists of names. If you sorted them all in one list, you would lose the structure.

Comment: If fears of sorting means loss of structure, you need to create a class to represent the record, so sorting on one of the fields will migrate the rest of the structure with the sort.